# Perforce replication

Tags: performance-testing, perforce, perforce-integrate, perforce-stream, perforce-branch-spec

I have a test server of perforce on which I want to have all the files which are on another perforce server. Along with files I want all other information such as versions, changelists, and every other information. In exact terms, I want my new server to be a replica of my old server. Please mention all the steps required.

Comment: Here is the manual: https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r16.2/manuals/p4dist/chapter.replication.html

Answer (score 0):

Copy all the files from P4ROOT from the original server to the test server.

Set P4ROOT on the test server to point to the path you copied them into.

Start p4d.